# Is there a simple Python webserver that can be compiled?

Tags: linux, debian, python, webserver

I am looking into very simple Python webservers such as [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) / HTTP.Server, but I can't find the answer to this.

Is there a simple webserver that can be compiled into .pyc, or really any kind of file that 1) runs on Debian, and 2) hides its own code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compile a Python web-server application to a stand-alone binary. Here is an example I just tried, where the standard [Python 2 SimpleHTTPServer module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) is compiled to a stand-alone binary using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Install PyInstaller:

```bsh
pip install PyInstaller
```

Move to a location where you don't mind generating some files:

```bsh
mkdir /tmp/python-server
cd /tmp/python-server
```

Generate the binary:

```bsh
pyinstaller --onefile /usr/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py
```

Run the generated binary (located in the `dist` subdirectory):

```
./dist/SimpleHTTPServer
```

You should see the server start as if you had run the script using the Python interpreter:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

There are many posts which discuss methods for compiling Python programs to stand-alone executables and which include alternatives to PyInstaller, e.g.:

- [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)
- [how to make my python script easy portable? or how to compile into binary with all module dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556424/how-to-make-my-python-script-easy-portable-or-how-to-compile-into-binary-with-a)